# From ExtJs 5 to 6. Simple code migration

Tags: extjs, extjs5, extjs6

I'm not sure why, but my teeny-weeny code that worked in `ExtJs 5`, now does not work in `ExtJs 6`. It is a very basic code and looks like this:

```
//TestApp/app.js

Ext.Loader.setConfig({enabled:true, disableCaching:true});
Ext.application({
    name:'TestApp',
    appFolder:'/TestApp',
    requires:['Ext.container.Viewport', 'Ext.layout.container.Border'],
    controllers:['TestAppController'],
    autoCreateViewport:true
});

============

//TestApp/view/Viewport.js

Ext.define('TestApp.view.Viewport',{
    extend:'Ext.container.Viewport',
    layout:'fit',
    initComponent:function(){
        Ext.apply(this,{
            layout:{
                type:'border'
            },
            items:[{
                region:'west',
                layout:'fit',
                width:500,
                collapsible:true,
                collapseMode:'mini',
                split:true,
                autoScroll:true
            },{
                region:'center',
                layout:'fit'
            }]
        });
        this.callParent(arguments);
    }
});

============

//TestApp/controller/TestAppController.js

Ext.define('TestApp.controller.TestAppControler',{
    extend:'Ext.app.Controller',
    init:function(){}
});
```

So, when I run my application, I see in the console, that first `ExtJS` css libraries are loaded, then the main `ext-all.js` file, then `app.js`, then `Viewport.js`, and finally `TestAppControler.js`. So, the library and all application source code is loaded ok - I clearly see it in the console. However, what I see in browser is just a blank page. I guess, I miss something, some piece of code, which is specific to `ExtJS 6` (like some launch command or something like that).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That might be related to the fact [`autoCreateViewport`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.1-classic/#!/api/Ext.app.Application-cfg-autoCreateViewport) is deprecated, try using [`mainView`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.1-classic/#!/api/Ext.app.Application-cfg-mainView) instead.

Comment: Would you be so kind to demonstrate would should I change in my code to make it work? I can't figure it out from documentation.

Comment: Try `mainView: 'TestApp.view.Viewport'`.

Comment: I tried it and now Viewport.js and TestAppControler.js are not even loaded

Comment: I think I should stress it again. Now with my initial code both `Viewport.js` and `TestAppControler.js` are loaded without any problem. The only problem is that no rendering takes place.

Comment: I will check it in a second.

Comment: Yes, your code is working. I will try to check it out, what happens when our code is in separate files.

Comment: I checked it. The code stops working when we move Viewport code to a separate file in `view/Viewport.js`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100308/discussion-between-cd-and-jacobian).

Comment: Thank you, sir! Now the code started to work! Many thanks!

Comment: @Jacobian So what was the root of the problem?